# Build a query to get grouped average of multiples many to one instances

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm having two models :

```py
class Club(models.Model):
   club_tag = models.CharField(primary_key=True)

class Player(models.Model):
   rating = models.FloatField(default=0)
   club = models.ForeignKey(Club, ...)
```

My objective is to get the top 10 of clubs with the best average rating players, in decreasing order.

In this situation the Club has an average rating (Which is its player's average) and is ranked thanks to it.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to pull this request, can someone give me directions please ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out, so here is the solution :

```py
Club.objects.annotate(avg_bcr=Avg("player__rating")).order_by("-avg_bcr")[:10]
```

Comment: Well done, that looks good to me